# add images to ppt template in R

Tags: r, image, powerpoint

I want to add images to a power point template where I have 34 slides in which all of them have only titles and page numbers on the slides. I am using `officer` library. I want to add images only on desired slides under the title.

In the code I am trying to add image to 5th slide where its showing the error: Error in slide$get_xfrm(type = type, index = index) : 
  type body is not available in the slide layout

```
my_pres <- read_pptx("myppt.pptx")

my_pres <- my_pres %>% on_slide(index = 5) %>%
    ph_with_img(type="body", index=3, src="imges/1.png", height=1.06, width=1.39)
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: I found this question while searching for "type body is not available in the slide layout". In my case, the solution was to remove type="body" because there was no such field (but also no need for it ...). Hope this helps someone !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to tell us what error your code is giving (if any)?

Tell us what you have in the 'my_pres' variable? Have you read in the template file (`read_pptx()`), have you loaded the slide (I know you have `on_slide()` but you've not piped this to the next line of code).

You need to be slightly more detailed.

Edit:

Based on your additional comments:

1. Your slide (5) most likely is a blank slide with no body section. WHich is why the error says "type body is not available".
2. Try to delete your 5th slide and use this code:

   ```
   my_pres <- my_pres %>% 
   add_slide(layout="Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>% 
   on_slide(index = 6) %>% 
   ph_with_img(type="body", index=1, src="imges/1.png", height=1.06, width=1.39)
   ```

2a. As you can see, creating a new slide and specifying a 'Title and Content' layout ensures that there's a 'body' to add your image to. Worked for me

3. Alternatively, make sure your 'slide 5' has BOTH a title and content sections. The content section is used as the body.

Comment: yes I've read ppt template file to 'my_pres'. I am using the above mentioned code to add image to 5th slide. I want executable code to add images to ppt in r

Comment: template that i've loaded has just the title in its slides with no body or content i've added blank page with title and content layout and executed code where it displays error:        Error in external_img(new_src, width = width/914400, height = height/914400) : 
  file.exists(src) is not TRUE

Comment: This error is simply telling you there's no image. Make sure there's an image (1.png) in the imges folder

Comment: Please remember to mark my suggsestion if it answers your question